# How to get the loss to change?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, decoder

The loss of this NN is getting stuck at 3.7666 but i can't tell why. I'm testing with about 50 training samples so would increasing this help improve the loss?

```
inp = open('train.csv',"rb")
X = pickle.load(inp)
X = X/255.0
X = np.array(X)
X = np.reshape(X,(-1,25425))


input_img =tf.keras.layers.Input(25425,)
encoded1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(750,activation=tf.nn.relu)(input_img)
encoded2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation=tf.nn.relu)(encoded1)
decode_encoder = tf.keras.layers.Dense(750,activation=tf.nn.relu)(encoded2)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(25425, activation='softmax')(decode_encoder)
# The input of the autoencoder is the image (input_img), and the output is the decoder layer (decoded)
autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, decoded)

encoder = tf.keras.Model(input_img, encoded2)

encoded_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(50,))
# The decoded only consists of the last layer
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-2](encoded_input)
# The input to the decoder is the vector of the encoder which will be fed (using encoded_input), the output is the last layer of the network (decoder_layer)
decoder = tf.keras.Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(X, X, epochs=50, shuffle=True)
```

I would like to have the model actually learn instead of getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try fitting them again.

But watch out for the over fitting problem.

A better approach would be if you increased your training set.